# find minimum number of ways to write the sum of square of value from 0 to n equals n

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, c++17, dynamic-programming

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
vector<int> memo;
class Solution{
    public:
    int minimum(int a , int b){
        if(a>b) return b;
        return a;
    }
    public:
    int MinSquares(int n , vector<int> memo)
    {
        if(n<= 3){
             return n;
        }
        if(memo[n]>-1) {
            return memo[n];
        }
        
        int m = n ;
        for(int i = 1 ; n-(i*i)>=0; i++){
            
            m = minimum(m, MinSquares(n - i*i , memo) + 1 );
        }
        memo[n]=m;
        return memo[n];
    }
    
    
};

// { Driver Code Starts.
int main(){
    int tc;
    cin >> tc;
    while(tc--){
        int n;
        cin >> n;
        Solution ob;
        vector<int> memo;
        memo.assign(n+1 ,-1);
        memo[0]=0;
        memo[1]=1;
        int ans = ob.MinSquares(n , memo);
        cout << ans <<"\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

1. I know that recurrence relation and tried solving it with using pen and paper.

> when trying output 100 it taking much more time than usual . I have spend at least 4 hour why there is no error in syntax and it is giving result for less than 100 .
> please help.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to solve a programming challenge of some sort - can you state the task itself?

Comment: Could you provide an example? It is not clear what you want to do. You claimed *total number of ways*, but in practice, you code calculates the minimum length of a sum of squares equal to n.

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear what you want to do. You claimed *total number of ways*, but in practice, you code calculates the minimum length of a sum of squares equal to n

Concerning the efficency issue that you mentioned, the problem is here:

```
int MinSquares(int n , std::vector<int> memo)
```

You are continuoulsly copying `memo`. This is solved by using a reference

```
    int MinSquares(int n , std::vector<int>& memo)
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

//vector<int> memo;
class Solution{
    public:
    int minimum(int a , int b){
        if(a>b) return b;
        return a;
    }
    public:
    int MinSquares(int n , std::vector<int>& memo) {
        if (n <= 3){
             return n;
        }
        if(memo[n] > -1) {
            return memo[n];
        }
        
        int m = n ;
        for(int i = 1 ; n-(i*i)>=0; i++){
            m = minimum (m, MinSquares(n - i*i , memo) + 1);
        }
        memo[n] = m;
        return memo[n];
    }
};

// { Driver Code Starts.
int main(){
    int tc;
    std::cin >> tc;
    while(tc--){
        int n;
        std::cin >> n;
        Solution ob;
        std::vector<int> memo;
        memo.assign(n+1 ,-1);
        memo[0] = 0;
        memo[1] = 1;
        int ans = ob.MinSquares(n , memo);
        std::cout << ans <<"\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks you so much . i am very much grateful to you.

Comment: Good. Please don't forget to accept this answer if it helps you.